# Wrong property is included in created object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am currently developing application using nestjs with fastify adapter

But something weird on object construction.

Following all the related classes, and methods:

1. Controller endpoint handler

```js
    @Get()
    @ApiOperation({
        description: "Get all user admin",
    })
    async findAll(
        @Query() filter: GetListAdminReqFilter,
        @Query() pagination: PaginatedReqDto
    ): Promise<RestRespDto<GetListAdminRespDto[]>> {
        return new RestRespDto({
            data: await this.adminService.findAll(
                new GetListAdminReqDto(filter, pagination)
            ),
        });
    }
```

2. The request dto

```js
export class GetListAdminReqDto extends PaginatedReqDto {
    constructor(filter: GetListAdminReqFilter, pagination: PaginatedReqDto) {
        super();
        this.filter = filter;
        this.pagination = pagination.pagination;
        this.page = pagination.page;
    }
    filter?: GetListAdminReqFilter;
}
```

3. The pagination req dto

```js
export class PaginatedReqDto {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        default: 10,
        description: "Number of items to retrieve",
    })
    pagination?: number;
    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        description: "Page number, e.g:1 ",
        default: 1,
    })
    page?: number;
}
```

4. The filter

```js
export class GetListAdminReqFilter {
    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @IsOptional()
    name?: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @IsOptional()
    email?: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional()
    @IsOptional()
    divisi?: string;

    @ApiPropertyOptional({ enum: AdminStatusEnum})
    @IsOptional()
    status?: AdminStatusEnum;
}
```

The result of `GetListAdminReqDto` object is following:

```js
{
  filter: [Object: null prototype] {
    pagination: '10',
    page: '1',
    name: 'asdfasdf',
    email: 'asdfasdf',
    divisi: 'asdfasdf'
  },
  pagination: '10',
  page: '1'
}
```

Why `pagination` and `page` is property also included in `filter`?, i dont understand what happened, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `@Query() filter: GetListAdminReqFilter` is receiving the `page` and `pagination` properties because your `ValidationPipe` is allowing properties outside of the DTO. You could alter the global `ValidationPipe.whitelist` property:

```js
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true, // this prevents properties outside the DTO to be ignored
    }),
  );
```